# Indecomposable module over a PID, Jacobson's Basic Algebra I - followup

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am trying to solve the question which already appeared here:
[Indecomposable $D$-module $M$, Jacobson's Basic Algebra I.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447080/indecomposable-d-module-m-jacobsons-basic-algebra-i)

Let $D$ be a PID. Let $M$ be a finitely generated $D$-module. Then

$$
M\ \text{is indecomposable}\Longleftrightarrow\ M=Dz,\ \text{where $\mathrm{ann}(z)=0$ or $\mathrm{ann}(z)=(p^n)$ with $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $p$ prime.}
$$

The answer was:

"In the case $D = \mathbb{Z}$, we see that the subgroups of the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$ form a single chain, and therefore any 2 nontrivial subgroups have nontrivial intersection.  Therefore the group cannot be decomposed into a nontrivial direct sum.  Now generalize this argument to an arbitrary p.i.d. (with $D$-submodules instead of just subgroups)."

I would appreciate any help with the generalization of the answer there to a PID.

Comment: Dear user, You might want to specify at the very beginning of your question that $D$ is notation for the PID in question.  (The reason being that $D$-module has another well-established default meaning; it signifies a module over the ring of differential operators, which is typically denoted $D$.)  Regards,

Comment: Actually, which implication are you interested in? For the "right to left" look at the ideals of $R/(p^n)$ and notice that these are of the form $(p^k)/(p^n)$ with $k=0,1,\dots,n-1$.

Comment: Yes, this was the implication. 
What I missed was use of the third Isomorphism theorm to prove what you wrote.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"$\Leftarrow$" Look at the ideals of $R/(p^n)$  and notice that these are of the form $(p^k)/(p^n)$  with $k=0,1,\dots,n−1$.