# Lasker-Noether theorem implies structure theorem for f.g. modules over PID's

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain#Generalizations) the Lasker-Noether theorem, i.e. that f.g. modules over a Noetherian ring have a primary decomposition, is a generalization of the structure theorem for f.g. modules over PID's.

I have no idea how to see that. For starters Lasker-Noether refers to submodules of a given module not to the module "as an object" and the decomposition into a direct sum suggests we should be dealing with suprema (sums), not infima, in Lasker-Noether.

Perhaps this is easy, but I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

From the wiki article:

> An equivalent statement is: every finitely generated module over a Noetherian ring is contained in a finite product of coprimary modules.

Over a PID, $R$ and $R/(p^n)$ is coprimary for any prime $p$, and since every f.g. module over a PID decomposes into a product of things like this, you can see the resemblance this way.

Comment: Sorry; my question was more along the lines of: "how do I prove the structure theorem for f.g. modules over PID's using Lasker-Noether?" (pretending I have never remotely tried to prove the former) not how do the theorems resemble each other. - Unfortunately, I don't know how to prove the above equivalent statement to Lasker-Noether either. And then I don't know how the "is contained in" can be improved to an isomorphism and why the coprimary modules can then be chosen to be of the form $R/(p^n)$.

Comment: @StefanPerko As to the last half of your last sentence, [it's not hard to show](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/606964/29335) the coprimary modules of a PID look like that. You're right about the first part of your last sentence... I will try to come up with an explanation.